# Render react component after typewriter-effect animation has finished

Tags: javascript, reactjs

https://hannarosenfeld.com/

Hi, I would like to display my social links after the typescript sentence has finished.

I am unsure how to achieve this, since I am kind of a beginner in React.

See my code below:

`

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
import Typewriter from "typewriter-effect";

import '../styles/base.css'

function TypewriterEffect() {
  return (
    <div className="typewriter">
      <Typewriter
       onInit={(typewriter)=> {
       typewriter
       .typeString("Hello World!")
       .pauseFor(1000)
       .deleteAll()
       .typeString("I am a web developer living and working in Philadelphia, PA.")
       .typeString(" Contact me through my social links below: ")
       .pauseFor(1000)
       .start()
       document.getElementsByClassName('social')[0].classList.add('visible')
       }}
       />
    </div>
  )
}
const IndexPage = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <header>
                <h1>
                    <Link className="hzr" to="/">&lt;hzr/&gt;</Link>
                </h1>
                <TypewriterEffect/>
                <p id="typewriter"></p>
                <div>
                    <Link className="social" to="https://github.com/hannarosenfeld">&gt; github</Link>
                </div>
            </header>
        </>
    )
}

export default IndexPage
```

`

I tried attaching a css attribute in the `onInit={(typewriter)=\> {..})}` function, sadly that did not work.

Code I used:

`document.getElementsByClassName('social')[0].classList.add('visible')`

- sadly this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to find anything on the Typewriter API that lets you know when it ended. However there is a simple way to achieve this, that is just calculating how long it takes to type everything out, and write a setTimeout for that time that changes a property that will show your links. Something like this

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import Typewriter from 'typewriter-effect';

const TypeWritter = () => {
  const [showLinks, setShowLinks] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setShowLinks(true);
    }, 20400);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="typewriter">
      <Typewriter
        onInit={(typewriter) => {
          typewriter
            .typeString('Hello World!')
            .pauseFor(1000)
            .deleteAll()
            .typeString(
              'I am a web developer living and working in Philadelphia, PA.'
            )
            .typeString(' Contact me through my social links below: ')
            .pauseFor(1000)
            .start();
        }}
      />
      {showLinks && <div>your links</div>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TypeWritter;
```

Example of the code running: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mui-krpgmy?file=TypeWritter.jsx

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by chaining the `callFunction` function and setting a state to display the social links

The `callFunction` if invoked after the `typeString` function, will be executed only after the typing animation completes. So this can be utilized to toggle a state that shows your links

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "gatsby";
import Typewriter from "typewriter-effect";

import "../styles/base.css";

function TypewriterEffect() {
  const [isAnimationComplete, setIsAnimationComplete] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="typewriter">
      <Typewriter
        onInit={(typewriter) => {
          typewriter
            .typeString("Hello World!")
            .pauseFor(1000)
            .deleteAll()
            .typeString(
              "I am a web developer living and working in Philadelphia, PA."
            )
            .typeString(" Contact me through my social links below: ")
            .callFunction(() => {
              // This will show the social link once the typing is done
              setIsAnimationComplete(true);
            })
            .pauseFor(1000)
            .start();
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
const IndexPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <header>
        <h1>
          <Link className="hzr" to="/">
            &lt;hzr/&gt;
          </Link>
        </h1>
        <TypewriterEffect />
        <p id="typewriter"></p>
        {isAnimationComplete && (
          <div>
            <Link className="social" to="https://github.com/hannarosenfeld">
              &gt; github
            </Link>
          </div>
        )}
      </header>
    </>
  );
};

export default IndexPage;
```